# Serve local video files for vlc-plugin with python

Tags: javascript, python, flask, video-streaming, vlc

I have a web application focused around playing videos.  It uses a flask api to serve the metadata.  I want to be able to pass a local filepath for a video to the client and allow the client to play that video.  Since you can't just load a local file, how can I serve the file to the browser?  I know there is simplehttpserver but I have files all over the place.

How can I set it up so that I can use the vlc plugin like in this post [Open video stream on VLC Player through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138244/open-video-stream-on-vlc-player-through-the-browser)?

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate.  I am asking how can I serve a file from a client-supplied filepath.  This can be any location, not just one directory of static css/html/js files I want served.  Since the client is getting the filepath from the server, I can validate that file is allowed to be served.

**UPDATE 2**

Still do not believe this is a duplicate as it is for consumption by a specific plugin, [vlc web plugin](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/).  I tried to use `send_from_directory` but it did not work.  Hopefully this makes it clearer.  If send_from_directory` is the right thing to use though, what is my error here?

On python my endpoint is as follows (using flask-restful):

```
from flask import Blueprint, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

class VideoServer(Resource):

    def get(self, filepath):
        path, file = os.path.split(filepath)
        return send_from_directory(path, file)

base_blueprint.add_resource(VideoServer, '/video_server/<string:filepath')
```

On the js side:

```
let videourl = config.api_server + '/video_server/' + filepath
let $video = $("<object>", {type: "application/x-vlc-plugin", data: videourl});
let $param = $("<param>", {name: "movie", value: videourl});
let $embed = $("<embed>", {type: "application/x-vlc-plugin", autoplay: "yes", loop: "no", target: videourl});
$video.append($param);
$video.append($embed);
$("#mydiv").append($video);
$("#mydiv").load();
```

Comment: `send_from_directory` is what you want, just like the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task I'd recommend a real server (as opposite to python simplehttpserver or flask embedded dev server).

So, maybe nginx ?

Comment: Well the problem is that the list of video files is dynamic based on user input and a real server has a static configuration

Comment: you could have nginx serving files from a folder, and create a symbolic link in that folder to the video file dynamically

Comment: i could but that is not very robust if i want to distribute this application cross-platform.  Would that become a headache if they already have nginx running separately?