# Open file in VLC from a href="path/of/file..WAV"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vlc

I'm looking a way to open a .wav49 on VLC with a link from my web app. Since files with .wav49 are not supported by `<audio>` tags. And I can't change the file type to a normal .wav or .mp3 due to several reasons.

The audio files are located in a shared folder on my server (which is a Windows Server 2016), so everyone on our network can access them.

The goal of my app is to make the audio file searching something easy.

I've been looking for options like change the format in backend and stream a .mp3 file to the audio tag or a plugin that allows to play .wav49 files but it seems that the easiest way is just to send the file to be opened on VLC.

The only I have for now is this

```
<a href="file:\\CENTRAL\path\audio.WAV">
```

I also tried with

```
<a href="file:\\CENTRAL\path\audio.WAV" download="test">
```

But neither works.

Only in Firefox, when I click the link ask me if I want to save it or just open it, but both of the options download the file. I don't want to download the file, I just want to launch an alert asking if the user wants to launch VLC and open the audio.

There are some examples of what I want to do, like roblox.com when a user click on the play button and he has the app installed, the browser launch the app on the local machine and gives the params of the game the user wants.

Another example is comodo remote control, when an user of comodo is in the web device manager and wants to begin a remote session, the user just click a button and an alert appears asking if the user wants to launch the remote control by Itarian app, if the user says yes, the app is launched in the local machine.

I found this [Open video stream on VLC Player through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138244/open-video-stream-on-vlc-player-through-the-browser) but it seems doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You should be able to associate the mime type to a binary app, so long as the mimetype is unique. Both Chrome and FF allow users to memorize the selection of save/open by type, and the OS will remember the association with the type and app. I'm guessing that the file now open without a custom mime type, and are handled in the safest/most generic way now. Adjust your server's type serving and things should work as you wish, given a few initial clicks and checkboxes per-user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the standard path separator to be used here is a forward-slash, also if you want to link to a local file you need to use the `file:///` prefix with three slashes. For network shares you would use two slashes: `file://smbhost/path`
So i would recommend you try the following:

```
<a href="file://CENTRAL/path/audio.WAV">
```

Hope this helps